# How to locate the latest version of Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.dll?

Tags: .net, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

What is the proper way to locate the latest version of `Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.dll`. There is a `ToolLocationHelper` class with `string GetPathToBuildTools(string toolsVersion)` method which returns the path.

The problem is that this class is contained in the `Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.dll` and that the older version of that dll is unable to locate the newer version:( (For instance, the 14.0 is not able to return path for 15.0.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am currently using [vswhere](https://github.com/Microsoft/vswhere/wiki/Find-MSBuild) to find the path of `msbuild.exe`.